# Windows Location don't redirect after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have these code with a XMLHttpRequest:

```
function Registrarse()
{
    conexionRegistrarse = new XMLHttpRequest();
    conexionRegistrarse.onreadystatechange = procesarRegistro;
    conexionRegistrarse.open('GET', 'index.php?registrarse=&username='+username+'&mail='+mail+'&pw='+contraseña+'&pwr='+repetircontraseña, true);
    conexionRegistrarse.send();
}

function procesarRegistro()
{
    var detalles = document.getElementById("labelUsername");

    if(conexionRegistrarse.readyState == 4)
    {
        if((conexionRegistrarse.responseText).indexOf("cuenta") == -1)
        {
            window.location = "http://localhost/index.php?creada";
        }
        else
        {
            detalles.innerHTML = conexionRegistrarse.responseText;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        detalles.innerHTML = "Cargando...";
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a succesfull register happen (these occurs when the responseText of the xmlhttprequest don't have the string "cuenta"), don't redirect me to: "index.php?creada". I try with assign() and neither work.

Comment: @r-rio what's the error message in developer console?

Comment: @inanc this is the problem, the console don't give me any error, so for this I don't know what it's wrong

Comment: @r-rio can you add ```console.log(this);``` just after ```procesarRegistro() { // here``` function and tell me result please.

Comment: @inanc there is: http://pastebin.com/P74x1Q08, if you need all tell me, because it's very bigger and have many sections

Answer (score 0):

I tested.
It works very well.
code As:

```js
var oAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
oAjax.open('GET', 'a', true);
oAjax.send();
oAjax.onload = function() {
  if (oAjax.status == 200) {
    window.location = 'http://baidu.com';
  }
};
```

as well, check your error message!

Comment: Still don't work. Affects that I have the form in a modal? The development console don't throw me any error